# Parsing XML as list of strings in python

Tags: python, xml

EDIT: XML File

```
-<corpus lang="en" id="subtask2-heterographic">


-<text id="het_1">

  <word id="het_1_1">'</word>

  <word id="het_1_2">'</word>

  <word id="het_1_3">I</word>

  <word id="het_1_4">'</word>

  <word id="het_1_5">m</word>

  <word id="het_1_6">halfway</word>

  <word id="het_1_7">up</word>

  <word id="het_1_8">a</word>

  <word id="het_1_9">mountain</word>

  <word id="het_1_10">,</word>

  <word id="het_1_11">'</word>

  <word id="het_1_12">'</word>

  <word id="het_1_13">Tom</word>

  <word id="het_1_14">alleged</word>

  <word id="het_1_15">.</word>

</text>


-<text id="het_2">

  <word id="het_2_1">I</word>

  <word id="het_2_2">'</word>

  <word id="het_2_3">d</word>

  <word id="het_2_4">like</word>

  <word id="het_2_5">to</word>

  <word id="het_2_6">be</word>

  <word id="het_2_7">a</word>

  <word id="het_2_8">Chinese</word>

  <word id="het_2_9">laborer</word>

  <word id="het_2_10">,</word>

  <word id="het_2_11">said</word>

  <word id="het_2_12">Tom</word>

  <word id="het_2_13">coolly</word>

  <word id="het_2_14">.</word>

 </text>
</corpus>
```

I am parsing an XML file on python and getting the text that I want. Each text tag represents a sentence in the XML file, and I want to put each sentence as separate list element inside a list.

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='subtask2-heterographic-test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

lst = []

for elem in root:
    for w in elem:
        lst.append(w.text)

>> ["'", "'", 'I', "'", 'm', 'halfway', 'up', 'a', 'mountain', ',', "'", "'", 'Tom', 'alleged', '.', 'I', "'", 'd', 'like', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'Chinese', 'laborer', ',', 'said', 'Tom', 'coolly', '.', 'Dentists', ...]
```

This just gives all words in the XML file without separating the sentence.
How can I fix it to put each sentence into the list as a list of strings?

Final expected output:

```
>> [["'", "'", 'I', "'", 'm', 'halfway', 'up', 'a', 'mountain', ',', "'", "'", 'Tom', 'alleged', '.'] , ['I', "'", 'd', 'like', 'to', 'be', 'a', 'Chinese', 'laborer', ',', 'said', 'Tom', 'coolly', '.'], ['Dentists', ...] ]
```

Comment: post your xml fragment at start

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry. Edited.

Comment: ok, we got the input. Now, post the final expected output please

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new list for each sentence:

```
sentences = []
for elem in root:
    sentence = []
    for w in elem:
        sentence.append(w.text)
    sentences.append(sentence)
```